# Show present windows shortcut does not work on Kubuntu 19.04

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kwin

As far as I remember, on previous Kubuntu version (18.10) when I hit Ctrl-F9 - KWin shows all open windows. But after upgrade to 19.04 it does not work anymore. In hotkeys settings Ctrl-F9 is still shortcut for this feature, but when I press it - nothing happens and I don't know neither how to launch it from command line to see errors nor where to see logs.

Comment: Are you sure compositing is enabled? `Shift+Alt+F12` toggles compositing which is needed for certain desktop effects including `Ctrl+F9`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Present Windows* is a desktop effect. For it, and certain other desktop effects, to work, *compositing* needs to be enabled. You can check the status by opening a terminal and running:

```
qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin supportInformation | grep -i composit
```

You may see something like this as the output:

```
Composite: yes; Version: 0x4
compositingMode: 1
useCompositing: true
compositingInitialized: true
windowsBlockCompositing: true
Compositing
Compositing is active
Compositing Type: OpenGL
```

You can toggle compositing on and off using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.

Alternatively, use the GUI to ensure that compositing is turned on when the system starts:

[image: Set compositing enabled on startup]

Comment: Thanks for answer. Checked "supportInformation" - "useCompositing: true". In system settings corresponding checkbox is already checked. Ctrl-F9 still does not work.

Comment: After reboot it started to work.

Comment: Question was about my personal laptop, now I faced same trouble on work PC. Compositing was enabled but command from this post shows "Compositing is not active". I solved it switching to XRender instead of OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks for updating! Does your work PC not have a nice GPU?

Comment: lspci shows "NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 610] (rev a1)"